# Get space between flexbox elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

Is it possible to get the space between two elements that use `justify-content: space-between` in a flexbox using JavaScript?

Comment: add margin to them?

Comment: @Pete I think he wants the number of pixels between them.

Comment: *anything* is possible with javascript!

Comment: @Mihailo Well it's a pretty poor question so it could mean anything, but in your case  I would test against the 2 offset lefts and then minus the width of the left one - (right element offset - (left element offset + left element width))

Comment: Well, the thing is, given this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7m73ann0/ I would like to make the boxes of the second list align with the first list. Using flexbox alone would require me to add dummy elements that I switch to invisible using `visibility: hidden`. The second idea was to calculate the spacing and apply that as margin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. [Example](http://jsbin.com/nowilip/edit?js,output)

```
function calcSpaceBetween(){
  var red_pos = $('#d1').position().left + $('#d1').width();
  var blu_pos = $('#d2').position().left;

  var space = blu_pos - red_pos;

  $('#space').text(space + ' px')
}
```

1. Calculate the position of the left one (red) + it's width
2. Find the position of the right one (blue)
3. `(blue.position) - (red) + (red.width)`

Comment: The question asked for *JavaScript*, not *JQuery*..

Answer (score 2):

Pure JavaScript [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7cv036m2/).

I made the same function as [Mihailo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6182569/mihailo) in pure JavaScript. Thought someone might find it useful. Please note that I'm relatively new to JavaScript so it might not be very well optimized.

```
function calcSpaceBetweenJavascript(){
    var red_elem = document.getElementById('d1')
    var blue_elem = document.getElementById('d2')
    var space_elem = document.getElementById('space')

    var red_pos = red_elem.offsetLeft + red_elem.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    var blu_pos = document.getElementById('d2').offsetLeft;

    var space = blu_pos - red_pos;
    space_elem.textContent = space + ' px';
}
```